# How to get related and upsell product images in order confirmation email in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I'm using Magento C.E 1.7. I need to send **order confirmation email** to customer including the **images** of **related products** and **upsell products** of the **purchased products**.

How can I do this in **magento**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the code for related products in email/order/items.phtml

```
 <?php
    $productId = $_item->getProduct()->getId(); //for order emails
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

    $related_product_collection = $_product->getRelatedProductCollection();
    $related_product_collection->AddStoreFilter();
    foreach($related_product_collection as $pdt)
    {
        $pdt_id=$pdt->getId();
        $model_rel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); //getting product model
        $_product_rel = $model_rel->load($pdt_id); //getting product object for particular product id
        $rel_name= $_product_rel->getName();
        $rel_price= number_format($_product_rel->getPrice(),2);

?>
                    <a href='<?php echo $_product_rel->getProductUrl();?>'><img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')
                                         ->getMediaUrl($_product_rel->getSmallImage()); ?>" 
                                width="120" height="120" alt="<?php echo $_product_rel->getName() ?>" />    </a>

        <?php

        }
        ?>
```

To get the upsell product collection using this

```
$upsell_product_collection = $_product->getUpSellProductCollection();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i can give you some skeleton code to use from your order item

when you send email order confirmation mail at that time you can get order product from order id or order object.

like this way.

```
 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')->addFieldToFilter('order_id',array

('eq'=>$order->getId()));
        foreach($collection as $item){ 
            if(!$item->getParent_item_id()){
                 $order_product =  $item->getId();

           }
          }?>
```

From above code you can take product id which is order by customer and you can get other detail like related product and upsell product as below

```
$related = $order_product->getRelatedProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
            ->addAttributeToSort('position', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
            ->addStoreFilter();

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {//if you want to exclude the products in the cart
            Mage::getResourceSingleton('checkout/cart')->addExcludeProductFilter($related,
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId()
            );
            $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($related);
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($related);

        $related->load();
```

**For Upsell**

```
$upsells = $product->getUpSellProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSort('position', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
            ->addStoreFilter()
        ;
        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {//if you want to exclude the products in the cart
            Mage::getResourceSingleton('checkout/cart')->addExcludeProductFilter($upsells,
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId()
            );

            $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($upsells);
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($upsells);

        //$upsells->setPageSize(10);//uncomment if you want to get only the first 10 items.

        $upsells->load();
```

but please check load time first it could be take time to clear this process.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: How can I get Images of related products and upsell products here?

Comment: you can use `if($product->getImage())
                    $_img = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($product->getImage()); }`

Comment: @SIBHIS, hope my answer is useful to you.it would be glad for me if u will acpet my ans nd vote up so some one can use in future

Comment: You have end up with   $upsells->load(); which will give upsell product collection right